# Google App Engine Datastore, how to deal with data inconsistency?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am porting a simple CRUD rest service and I realized that the data-store consistency is not immediate.

Currently I make a POST request to create the entity with and get the status code 202 (because I know that the entity is not persisted yet).
Then a GET request to get the created entity, if the status is 404 I sleep during two seconds, and I keep requesting until I get a 200.

Is this an acceptable way to deal with data-store eventual consistency?
Should I make the same read trys until I got the entity in the server side?
Is there an alternative?

Comment: This has been addressed in similar questions regarding eventual consistency and in many articles outside s.o. In general thats not the best strategy.

Comment: Oh, I'll look for them, would you like to recommend one?

Comment: Sorry i just remember similar questions asked. Note that datastore has a sync/async put param which handles your case as long as you get by key.

Answer (score 2):

Your server-side Java code which creates the entity in response to the `POST` can then get that entity's `Key` by its method `.getKey()`.  Then, it uses `KeyFactory.keyToString` (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory#keyToString(com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key) ) on that `Key` to obtain a "websafe string" form of the key which it sends to your client as part of the response.

The client-side `GET` can then include that "websafe string" and the server can make the `Key` object again using `KeyFactory.stringToKey`.

Last but not least, a `datastore.get(key)` on an instance of `DataStoreService`, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService , returns the corresponding entity **with strong consistency** -- a fact that's unfortunately not clearly documented for Java but holds just as well as for Python, for which it **is** clearly documented at https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore/#h.tf76fya5nqk8 ...

So, by properly dancing the key-based minuet, you should be fine without needing to retry-and-wait on 404s!-)